# load balancing multiple gateway using route and iptables

Tags: linux, gateway, route, load-balancing

under linux, how do I load balancing multiple gateway by using route, note that I have **one input** interface lets say `eth0`, and **one output** interface lets say `eth1`. `eth1` can connect to **multiple IP gateway** where each of those gateway has its own internet provider

Comment: Load balancing issues are probably more suitable (and likely to be answered) on Server Fault, our sister site dedicated to sysadmins. I'm migrating your question there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use iproute2. Details on setting that up are at http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html